# Adding control at runtime, not following panels padding properties

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik

I am adding controls at run-time to my `Panel`, but the are not following the panels `Padding` property.

The `Label` below, just gets placed in the very top left of my panel. I have my panel at `20,20,20,20` in `Padding`, but it's still not working. Any ideas? Thanks!

```
//Thickness Combo Clicked\\
private void Thickness_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RadMenuItem item = sender as RadMenuItem;
    switch (item.Text)
    {
        case "6":
            RadLabel label = new RadLabel();
            label.Text = "Test";
            radPanel1.Controls.Add(label);
            break;
        case "20":
            //
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Padding` of `Panel` is just respected by those child controls which you have set their `Dock` property to a value different from `None`. In fact, as mentioned in documentations 
The [`Padding`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.padding(v=vs.110).aspx) property of `Panel` is a more general realization of the [`DockPadding`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol.dockpadding(v=vs.110)) property of a `ScrollableControl` and the property property determines the border inside of this control for docked components.

So in above case which you added the `Label` without setting `Dock` property, the label and panel controls are working properly and your label will be shown at `0,0` location.

To solve the problem you need to set the `Location` manually or use a `TableLayoutPanel` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the info!